# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift

Error details:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and 'Int'

```
for i in class_User.day {
    if i == 1 {
        print(i)
        strdays += "1"
    } else if (i == "2") {
        print(i)
        strdays += "- 2"
    }
}
```

I am using this for array which comes from API but I am getting this error can you please help

Comment: does class_user.day has a int value with any type?

Comment: class_user is an my model while api calling which field are coming i create model of that and there is an array in api with name of days

Comment: Can you share your declaration of `class_user` and the API call you use to populate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare the two different type values. try this.

```
if let days =  class_User.day as? [String]
{
   for i in days {
      if i == "MON" {
        print(i)
     } .....
  }
}
```